# How to read a resource file in C#

Tags: c#, resources, windows-services

I have added a resource file to my project (C#, windows service - TopShelp):

[image]

I have added a text file to the resource:

[image]

Now I want to read the test file, this is what I have tried:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("My.Project.Name.Resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

It does not find anything, `ResourceSets` count = 0.

**Update**

As suggested in the comments, I also tried adding the resource under:

Project > Properties > Resources

[image]

And tried the following code, which did not find anything:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("My.Project.Name.Resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Comment: In this case you have strongly typed (named) resources available. Why dont need to find it this way.

Comment: Getting the first argument for the ResourceManager constructor wrong is a universal problem.  Always favor using the resource designer, it never gets it wrong.  Project > Properties > Resources tab, click the link if necessary to create the project file.

Comment: @HansPassant: thanks. Do you mean instead of adding `Resources` file, I should just right click the project and add the text file as a resource?

Comment: No, use Project > Properties > Resources.

Comment: @ZorgoZ: thanks... I am sorry, I am not following... I just want to include a text file in my project and read it...

Comment: Add a `.resources` extension to your first argument

Comment: @JohanP: it already ends with .Resources? do you mean I should use: `My.Project.Name.Resources.resources`?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini Yes

Comment: @HansPassant: I tried adding the text file under: Project > Properties > Resources... I still cannot find anything... do I need to change my code too?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini put a breakpoint somewhere and inspect this code `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()`

Comment: I can't really guess why you have such a problem using it, smells like you've got some learning to do.  Press F1 at the resource designer tab, take half an hour or so.

Comment: In your case, `Resources.Designer.cs` should define a class for your resources, you can probably access your text file as `Resources.stop_words_utf8` in your code directly, there should be no need to manually work with ResourceManager in this case.

Comment: You just reached to `My.Project.Name.Resources` you need to go deep inside `Designer.Resources`, Whats value in `rm` you are getting??

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: thanks a lot! that solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your Resources.Designer.cs file. You should have there static string property named stop_words_utf8 (or whatever name for the file you choose). You use it like this:

```
Resources.stop_words_utf8
```

It is static string property

Answer (score 1):

You can always try:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "MyCompany.MyProduct.MyFile.txt";

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Check that your file exists through [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_Assembly_GetManifestResourceNames) method.

Comment: Thanks, so the file has to be added as a resource first, then I can read it like the above?

Answer (score 0):

We dont even need to do that , add the resource to your project and write the followig code , as it is text file already you do not need to use stream reader.

name of the file = AtomsData.txt

var data = Resources.AtomsData;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).